# TFS work items associated with a check-in is limited to 100?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am currently using visual studio 2010; our TFS version is 2012. In visual studio, team explorer, pending changes, I cannot relate more than 100 work items  with a check-in using the "Add Work Item by ID" option. If I have 200 work items, and try to use the "Add Work Items by ID" option by cut & paste using a comma-delimited list of work item id's, only 100 get related to the check in. If I remove the 100th work item, and add another work item that was previously related to the check-in UNsuccessfully, it is added. When I attempt to REassociate that same 100th work item I previously UNassociated, it is not associated because there are 100 work items already associated with the check-in. How can I remove this limitation as there are sometimes hundreds of work items that need to be associated with some of my check-ins?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you are doing commits that apply to **hundreds** of work items, you are doing something incredibly, mind-boggling bizarre and unexpected. One commit is generally intended to be tied to one and exactly one work item. *Maybe* two. Commits should be small and granular.

Comment: @DanielMann We use Merge Down, Copy Up; the "hundreds" of work items are attached to a check-in that is the result of a merge between two branches; the"hundreds" of work items to be attached to the check-in, represent all the work items of the branch that are being merged that have been resolved, closed, etc. Our QA then knows what work items have been merged up to the resulting branch.

Comment: @gangelo Just something to add to this interesting conversation to help you with your question: how often do you do this _Merge Down_, _Copy Up_ operation?

Comment: @mguassa We have 3 branches - Prod, Main and Dev. Merge Downs take place frequently, every other day or so (Prod -> Main -> Dev) to make sure check-ins are merged down the branch hierarchy; Copy Ups take place every iteration/release which is about every 3 weeks or so (Prod <- Main, Main <- Dev).